# Find all the non-negative integer solutions of a linear equation

Tags: equation-solving

For the linear equation

```
x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4] + x[5] == n
```

Is there any efficient way to find all the non-negative integer solutions of this equation when n is large?

Answer (score 5):

```
FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, #], #2] &[5,4]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

For large `n` it would be better to use `IntegerPartitions` to avoid solutions that are identical up to permutation. Using the second and third arguments, `IntegerPartitions[#, {5}, Range[0, #]]` gives all the solutions `{x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5]}` with the structure `x[1] >= x[2] >= x[3] >= x[4] >= x[5]`

```
IntegerPartitions[#, {5}, Range[0, #]] &[12]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Wenzhe, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PadLeft[IntegerPartitions[n]]
```

Comment: `PadLeft[IntegerPartitions[12, 5]]`